# How do you return different lists based on an enum?

Tags: c#, generics

I've seen that people have asked similar questions but they're normally using complex types and resolve to use interfaces instead. What I would like to do is pass back either list, list or list depending on an enum. Something like this:

```
private IList<T> GetValueFromType<T>(MyData data)
{
    switch (data.SomeType)
    {
        case MyType.Percent:
           var PercentValues = new List<double>();
           PercentValues.Add(data.CompAPercentage);                   
           PercentValues.Add(data.CompBPercentage);
           return (T)PercentValues;
        case MyType.Money:
           var MoneyValues = new List<decimal>();
           MoneyValues.Add(data.CompAMoney);
           MoneyValues.Add(data.CompBMoney);
           return (T)MoneyValues;
        case MyType.Months:
           var MonthValues = new List<int>();
           MonthValues.Add(data.CompAMonth);
           MonthValues.Add(data.CompBMonth);
           return (T)MonthValues;
    }
}
```

This shows an error on all 3 return statements saying the type can't be converted to 'T'. Is this possible / advised or is this a code smell?

Comment: You are attempting to cast to T rather than IList<T>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically can't do this.

It is possible to circumvent the static type-checking as Mike's answer says in order to make `GetValueFromType<T>` compile, but how will you invoke it? Your calling code will need to specify T, eg.

`var myValue = GetValueFromType<int>(myData)`

because there's no way to infer T from the call itself, and when the method tries to return a list which doesn't match your choice of T you'll get an InvalidCastException. Given that you need to interrogate `MyData` to find out how to call this method safely, you might as well have the switch in the calling code.

Comment: Yes you're right. I can get it to compile now, but working it through I don't know the type of the list I want at the time I make the call so I get the error that it can't be inferred from it's usage.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat dangerous because it loses some of the power of static type checking and is easy for callers to get wrong. The compiler will flag it. You may need to insert an (object) cast to tell the compiler you really want to make the cast:

```
return (IList<T>) (object) MonthValues;
```

Comment: Thanks. I had been messing about with different things and forgotten to update the cast properly, though you don't need the (object) cast aswell